# Sass sourcemap on Firefox Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: firefox, sass, firebug, ubuntu-16.04, source-maps

How can I set sourcemaps for sass files on Firefox - Firebug (I'm having Ubuntu 16.04 on VirtualBox), so I can inspect the sass code for ruby-on-rails or php projects? I 'm not entirely sure, but I guess would be a system or a firefox setting, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebug does **not** have [support for source maps](https://github.com/firebug/firebug/issues/5894) and it is [not working anymore once multi-process Firefox is enabled](https://blog.getfirebug.com/2016/06/07/unifying-firebug-firefox-devtools/).

Therefore I suggest you use the Firefox DevTools, which support [source mapping](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger/How_to/Use_a_source_map).